# Android Java specific music folder

Tags: java, android, directory, external

Found a tutorial to follow which displays music on my phone. Is it possible for me to look at just one folder instead of all the folders that contain music on my external?

```
    String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + " != 0";
    String[] proj = { MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME};

    Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    musiccursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, proj, selection, null);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

selection =

```
Mediastore.Audio.Media.Data + " like ? ";
```

Selection args =

```
new String[]{"%" + folder path + "%"}
```